# `Load failed` on Safari and `ERR_CONNECTION_RESET` on Chrome when uploading an image via Next.js, Formidable, and Express

Tags: express, http, next.js, fetch

I have an Intel NUC server running Ubuntu Server. It is hosting a Next.js application and one Node Express application. The Next.js application is made available to the internet, while the Express server is not.

The Next.js client is making a fetch request to its own API at `/pages/api/upload/[room]`, where another request to the Express server is made in order to upload an image.

Here is the code for the express server.

**app.js**

```js
var express = require('express')
var path = require('path')
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser')
var cors = require('cors')

var targetsRouter = require('./routes/targets')

var app = express()

app.use(cors())
app.use(express.json())
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }))
app.use(cookieParser())
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')))

app.use('/targets', targetsRouter)

/** Error responder. */
app.use((error, req, res, next) => {
  console.log(new Date(), `(${req.ip} ${req.url})`, '\x1b[31m', error)

  res.status(error.status ?? 500).json({ message: error.message })
})

module.exports = app
```

**routes/targets.js**

```js
var express = require('express')
var router = express.Router()
const fs = require('fs/promises')
const path = require('path')

const pendingDirectory = 'public/images/uploads/pending'
const approvedDirectory = 'public/images/uploads/approved'

router.post('/upload/:room', async function (req, res, next) {
  try {
    const filePath = req.body.filePath
    const fileName = req.body.fileName
    const roomParam = req.params.room

    /** Check if the filepath. */
    if (typeof filePath !== 'string' || typeof fileName !== 'string') {
      const error = new Error('Invalid or missing file.')
      error.status = 400

      throw error
    }

    /** Move the file to the pending folder. */
    const path = `${pendingDirectory}/${roomParam}`
    await fs.mkdir(`${path}`, { recursive: true })
    await fs.rename(filePath, `${path}/${fileName}`)

    /** Send client response. */
    res.json({
      message: 'Success, image was uploaded and awaiting approval.',
      file: `${fileName}`,
    })
  } catch (error) {
    next(error)
  }
})

module.exports = router
```

Here is the code for a [replicate-able Next.js environment](https://github.com/graysonlee123/axeos-debug).

I'm running into an issue where *sometimes* I get an error back on the client: `Load failed` on Safari (mobile) and `ERR_CONNECTION_RESET` in Chrome (desktop). I can't seem to replicate when the error happens. It does seem to happen more often when using larger images.

When I debug this by connecting my iPhone to my Mac and using Safari web inspector, all I get is "Failed to load resource: The network connection was lost." The network tab makes it look like the fetch request was never even sent.

I know that `ERR_CONNECTION_RESET` means the connection was suddenly terminated. I don't know how to debug this, and I was hoping someone could help or give me pointers into this issue?